# What is armeabi and why they use it?

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I see this library (armeabi) many times when I explore open sources.

I net searched for an explanation of it, but all the results I found are talking ABOUT it and not defining it.

What is this armeabi and why are they using it in Android applications?

Comment: [Those](/q/56824557 "What is the difference between armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86?") [two](/q/3594394 "What are 16, 32 and 64-bit architectures?") are directly related and [those](/q/33228158) [are](/q/46453457) [further](/q/30782848) related questions.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Android devices have CPUs. Many of those CPUs are based on the ARM architecture, while some are based on x86, and a few others are based on other stuff like MIPS.

Some Android apps use the Native Development Kit (NDK) to create C/C++ code to link into their app. C/C++ code needs to be compiled for a specific CPU architecture. The NDK places the version of the C/C++ code compiled for each architecture into an architecture-specific directory. One of those directories is `armeabi/`, which is for a generic ARM CPU. There is also `armeabi-v7/` (for an ARM v7-compatible CPU), `x86/` (for x86 CPUs), etc.

Answer (score 52):

**ABI** - Application Binary Interface

**EABI** - Embedded Application Binary Interface

So ARMEABI are **compiled binaries** matching your android device's CPU architecture.

e.g.

**arm64-v8a** (Nexus 5x) - 64bit - ARM Cortex-A35, ARM Cortex-A53, ARM Cortex-A57, ARM Cortex-A72, ARM Cortex-A73

**armeabi-v7a** - 32bit - ARM Cortex-A5, ARM Cortex-A7, ARM Cortex-A8, ARM Cortex-A9, ARM Cortex-A12, ARM Cortex-A15, ARM Cortex-A17

[image]

To include ***.so** binary **jniLibs** using Android Studio 2.3 place them in `src/main/jniLibs` folder and add the following configuration to your *.gradle file:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'jniLibs', include: ['*.so'])
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I recently saw a pretty good [article](https://medium.com/android-news/controlling-apk-size-when-using-native-libraries-45c6c0e5b70a) related to the different CPUs and suggestions on maintaining APK size while supporting them. The report provides some info for the following at the end:

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- arm64-v8a
- X86
- X86-64
- mips
- mips64

Comment: Give a brief description of them from the article bcoz links will be rot