# Android studio doesn't start emulator

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-emulator, android-manifest

I created this project with PhoneGap / Node.js tutorial.
I am having problems with Android Studio. The emulator doesn't start when I try to run it. I created a virtual device with these configurations:

```
Android 5.1.1 - API 22
512MB ram
API 22
3,3 WQVGA 240x400 ldpi
Android armeabi-v7a
Emulated:    uncheked
performance: unchecked
```

I am using Java SDK 1.7.

In my manifest, I have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

The Android Studio never displays the emulator and I cannot run my app.

[image]

My android virtual device configuration:
[image]

Update: these are the downloaded versions
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check if you have SDK tools for API 22. This could be the issue. Check and share your result.

Comment: Can you also include a screenshot of your created AVD ?

Comment: @Rollno1 yes, I downloaded the API 22, I think it too, but after downloaded still not work.

Comment: @Codester I added my virtual device image, is it you wanna see?

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira Yes I can see it, Can you change the **Android 5.1.1 armeabi - v7a** to **x86** and then let us know the results ? [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042175/what-is-armeabi-and-why-they-use-it)

Comment: @Codester I change it, but still doenst work, I post a new print to you see my downloaded versions. I am selected x86 version API 22, but still doenst work. I just create the project and import in Android studio, I selected the buld.gradle in C:\Program Files\nodejs\my-app\platforms\android, Is necessary change something in this file?

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira I never seen something like this before. Can you use the API 21 Android 5.0.1 ? Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615127/android-studio-unknown-emulator-running-and-cant-be-terminated) I hope that helps.